# DirectX Architecture Resources

Tags: direct3d, directx-10, direct3d10

Can anybody **please please** post links to **DX Driver architecture** which covers topics like block manager etc etc. Hell lot of google search but i am not satisfied with what i get from google. nvidia specific resources preferred.
MSDN also seems to focus on DX APIs only. It dont curse them as they don't control the drivers.

Comment: You're going to use DirectX but DX API reference is not what are you looking for?! Main idea of DX is abstraction (to some extent) from hardware. No doubt you can use NVIDIA specific capabilities via DX but it's still a DX API. The question is not clear.

Comment: Yes. What architecture basically DX follows is the question. Or more precisely if you are NVIDIA, a simple question to you is :  
"Whats your DX Driver's architecture"? Somewhat more deeper than http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219679(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but may be **"[A trip through the Graphics Pipeline 2011](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/)"** will be useful for you...?

I believe, that some aspects of **"D3D/OpenGL graphics pipelines as actually implemented by GPUs"** can give you a hits of what to search to retrieve more actual information about drivers.

Comment: thats certainly a good one though I have been there before posting here :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that might help you understand DX driver architecture:

[How do libraries such as DirectX relate to drivers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86311/how-do-libraries-such-as-directx-relate-to-drivers)

[Direct3D device driver development on Windows (A thread in GameDev Forum)](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/264853-direct3d-device-driver-development-on-windows/)

[What is the Architecture behind DirectX?](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-DIRECTX-Architecture-Behind-DirectX)

[DirectX FAQ on programmers Heaven](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/DIRECT-X-FAQ)

[Windows driver API basics](http://www.staudio.de/kb/english/drivers/)

[WDM I/O Concepts](http://www.scribd.com/doc/61435580/WDM-Input-Output-Concepts)

I hope that helped!